# Need help to train this model for Diabetic Retinopathy problem

Tags: keras

I am training a model to try to solve the problem "Diabetic retinopathy", which is widely known to start in this world.
Here I leave the code of what I have so far.

```
  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    rotation_range=15,  # randomly rotate pictures
    width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly translate pictures
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.2,  # randomly apply shearing
    zoom_range=0.2,  # random zoom range
    horizontal_flip=True,
    #samplewise_std_normalization=True,
    #featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    validation_split=0.30)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=trainLabels,
        directory='resized_train_cropped/resized_train_cropped/',
        x_col="image",
        y_col="level",
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=10,
        class_mode='categorical',
        color_mode='rgb', #quitar o no quitar
        subset='training')


validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=trainLabels,
        directory='resized_train_cropped/resized_train_cropped/',
        x_col="image",
        y_col="level",
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=10,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='validation')

model=Sequential()
model.add(vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights=None, input_tensor=None, input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling=None, classes=5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='predictions'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer='adam',
            metrics=['acc', 'mse'])

#Model Summary
model.summary()

log_dir="logs\\fit\\" +'Prueba'+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

parada=callbacks.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='acc',mode='max',verbose=1,restore_best_weights=True,patience=3)
learningRate=callbacks.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.1, verbose=1, mode='min', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0, patience=5)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=50,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=30,
    validation_freq=1,
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback,parada])
```

As you can see I am using the pre-trained model VGG16.
With these preprocessing parameters I am unable to exceed 0.75 accuracy, I have tested a multitude of different parameters and cannot advance.

First of all I don't know if I am doing the rescaling well, I understand that apart from the operation I do: `rescale = 1. / 255` it is necessary to divide each image between its mean to get a higher score. But I do not know how to do it.

Second, I would like to use parameters such as `featurewise_std_normalization`. But these require a fit of the set of images. The problem is that I cannot pass the entire `train_generator` to the `train_datagen.fit ()` function, since this is how memory collapses. I would like to know how it is done to pass small samples of images and thus be able to do it.

I have another question about the stop condition, I have configured it to restore the best weights, but whenever the algorithm is going to do this the algorithm stops.

Finally, I would appreciate any other advice and fault you see in my code. I am really new to this and as much as I look at documentation I don't stop finding myself lost. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see I am using the pre-trained model VGG16.

By the code given it looks like you are not using pretrained, since `weigts=None`. You also don't need to specify `classes=5` since you are adding your own top to the network and `include_top=False`.

> First of all I don't know if I am doing the rescaling well, I understand that apart from the operation I do...
>
> Second, I would like to use parameters such as featurewise_std_normalization....

You can do the preproessing of the images ahead, load the dataset image by image and calculate your values and agregating them.

> I have another question about the stop condition, I have configured it to restore the best weights, but whenever the algorithm is going to do this the algorithm stops.

That is the purpose of the `EarlyStopping` callback. It stops the training based on your condition and then restores the weights. That is, after 3 epochs, if the accuracy doesn't increase, stop training and restore best weights.

> Finally, I would appreciate any other advice and fault you see in my code.

There is no obivous way to improve the code, just experiment and see what happens.

Comment: So how can i continue the train process after restoring the best weights?

Comment: You just call `fit_generator` again, you can use other data aswell, you can also freeze layers if you want, and train afterwards.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it anserwed your questions.